# How much success is there working on ASP.NET decompiled by Reflector?

Tags: asp.net, decompiling, reflector

I just finished a small project where changes were required to a pre-compiled, but no longer supported, ASP.NET web site.  The code was ugly, but it was ugly before it was even compiled, and I'm quite impressed that everything still seems to work fine.

It took some editing, e.g. to remove control declarations, as they get put in a generated file, and conflict with the decompiled base class, but nothing a few hours didn't cure.

Now I'm just curious as to how many others have had how much success doing this.  I would actually like to write a CodeProject article on defining, if not automating, the reverse engineering process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Will:
> >     Due to all the compiler sugar that exists in the .NET platform

Fortunately this particular application was incredibly simple, but I don't expect to decompile into the original code, just into code works like the original, or maybe even provides an insight into how the original works, to allow 'splicing' in of new code.

Answer (score 1):

Due to all the compiler sugar that exists in the .NET platform, you can't decompile a binary into the original code without extremely sophisticated decompilers.  For instance, the compiler creates classes in the background to handle enclosures.  Automating this kind of thing seems like it would be a daunting task.  However, handling expected issues just to get it to compile might be scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

i had to do something similar, and i was actually happier than if i had the code. it might have taken me less time to do it, but the quality of the code after the compiler optimized it was probably better than the original code.  So yes, if its a simple application, is relatively simple to do reverse engineer it; on the other hand i would like to avoid having to do that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If it was written in .NET 1.1 or .NET 2.0 you'll have a lot more success than anything compiled with the VS 2008 compilers, mainly because of the syntactic suger that the new language revisions brought in (Lambda, anonymous classes, etc).

As long as the code *wasn't* obfuscated then you should be able to use reflector to get viable code, if you then put it into VS you should immidiately find *errors* in the reflected code.

Be on the look out for variables/ method starting with `<>`, I see that a lot (particularly when reflecting .NET 3.5).

The worst you can do is export it all to VS, hit compile and determine how many errors there are and make a call from that.

But if it's a simple enough project you should be able to reverse engineer from reflector, at least use reflector to get the general gist of what the code is doing, and then recode yourself.